# How to configure Entity Framework 6 for ASP.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to configure a new project to use `Entity Framework 6` with `ASP.net Core`, I'm using the full `.net` framework in order to be able to use `Entity Framework 6`. This is a project that was in MVC before and I need to migrate it to Core.
This is what I've done(I have two projects, one `Asp.net Core` and a `class library` that contains some classes and the `DBContext class`):

***`appsettings.json`:***

```
  "Data": {
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "MyConnection": "Server=namedatabase.database.secure.windows.net,1433;Database=database_Name;User ID=blahblah;Password=blahblah;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
    }
  }
```

***`Startup.cs`***

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
         services.AddScoped<MyDBContext>(_ => new LIGDataContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")));
        }
```

I have the `DBContext` class separated in a `class library(.dll)`:

```
  public class MyDBContext: DbContext
    {
 public MyDBContext(string connString): base(connString)
        {
        }
```

But I have this code inside some controllers of my `asp.net Core` project and I'm not sure how to refer now to the `DBContext` instance... Clearly is asking for the `connString` parameter, this is the first time I'm doing this and I'm not sure which is the best approach to do this, `ConfigurationManager` is not available anymore in `Core` what do I need to do? This is Entity Framework 6 no Entity Framework Core..

```
     public class MyController : Controller
        {
           public ActionResult MyAction()
              {
                  var _ctx = new MyDBContext();
                  return PartialView(_ctx.FormsiteApplications.Where(f => f.Application).OrderBy(f => f.Title).ToList());
              }
```

Comment: You are configuring the injection of DbContext in `ConfigureServices()` with `services.AddScoped<MyDBContext>(_ => new LIGDataContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")));`. Any reason to not let the DbContext be injected into Controller through property (you are instantiating it `var _ctx = new MyDBContext();`) ? I think that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

dime2lo is right, you can inject the DbContext to the controller.

```
codepublic class StoreController : Controller
{
    private DefaultDbContext _dbContext = null;
    public StoreController(DefaultDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this._dbContext = dbContext;
        //Do something with this._dbContext ...
    }
}
```

or create a context factory

```
public class DefaultDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<DefaultDbContext>{
public DefaultDbContext Create()
{
    return new DefaultDbContext("Server=XXXX ;Database=XXXXX;Trusted_Connection=True;");
}
```

[Reference : Getting Started with ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework 6](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html)